# Clang Static Analyzer doesn't find the most basic problems

Tags: c, clang, llvm, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I wanted to try out the clang static analyzer. I'm on Windows and built clang with Visual Studio. It seems to work, but at the same time it seems to be extremely useless.

I made an example file

**example.c**

```
int main(void) 
{
    int h = 0;
    return 1/h;
}
```

Calling `scan-build gcc -c example.c` finds no error.

**example.c**

```
int main(void) 
{
    int h;
    return 1/h;
}
```

Calling `scan-build gcc -c example.c` finds no error.

**example.c**

```
int main(void) 
{
    return 1/0;
}
```

Calling `scan-build gcc -c example.c` finds no error.

If these most basic errors can't be found (and they can be found by clang itself), how can the static analyzer be of any use?

My `gcc` is MinGW if that matters. I also tried substituting `clang` but there's just nothing happening.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would indeed appear that the tool is pure crap. Based on your tests, you don't need someone on the internet to tell you that, you already came to this conclusion. Simply uninstall it and get another one.

Comment: @Lundin There seem to be a lot of projects putting faith into the LLVM-framework. For example the Rust language, which is backed by the Mozilla Foundation. I just can't imagine the included static-analyzer is that useless. Maybe I am missing something very basic here, e.g. some hidden configuration.

Comment: I haven't used this particular static analyser, but many others. As a rule of thumb, always assume they are broken beyond repair.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, and never consider that you might be using it wrong or for the wrong thing, that would be ridiculous.

Comment: @Lundin I've tried a few usable ones, e.g. Polyspace, which is very slow, but gives useful results. However the licensing costs are prohibitive for my department.

Comment: @nwp If I submit a bug report and the tool vendor acknowledges that it is a bug, then I'm fairly certain that I am using the tool correctly. This is what I used to do when I got false positive, until I got tired of hearing "we'll fix it later".

Comment: @CodeMonkey just out of curiosity, if you test it with exactly the same example given in [their page](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html#core_checkers) about division by zero, does it complain?

Comment: @SamirAguiar No not even there.

Comment: My theory is that there are errors that are easy and fast to find, so clang just finds them for you. And then there are errors that are difficult to find and require costly analysis that massively increase your compile times which therefore cannot be enabled in clang, so they are moved into the dedicated static analyzer. That static analyzer doesn't repeat what clang is already doing, that would just be wasted effort. The test cases you have are simple and therefore nothing the static analyzer even considers. Use the tools in combination instead of expecting one tool to find everything.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. These examples work fine for me, using both clang-3.6 (from a debian package) and a fairly recent svn of clang-5.0. (Of course, I'm not trying on Windows.)

Comment: By the way, you can specify the `-v` option (immediately after the `scan-build` command) up to three times, to receive increasingly amounts of debugging output, which might help you understand why it is not managing to do a static analysis on your system.

Comment: @rici I'm using the current build from SVN. I used the -v option, now it tells me it creates the report directory which it deletes afterwards. I guess it just doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Other people seem to manage to get it to work on windows, but it seems that the install has some gotchas. I don't have a windows environment handy so I can't help you, but there were some instructions for Windows install which Google found me. Worst comes to worst, its a Perl script so normsl debugging techniques should be possible.

Comment: I confirm that on Linux (clang 3.8) all these examples generate the relevant warnings ("a.c:4:13: warning: Division by zero", "b.c:4:13: warning: The right operand of '/' is a garbage value", "c.c:3:13: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]"). Most probably in your case the call to the compiler isn't properly intercepted.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and tweaking my Makefile as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309035/328817 meant scan-build started emitting warnings.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60771584/891439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scan-build` driver substitutes an "interception" command in place of the compiler when doing analysis, so you need to make sure to use a "variable" as the name of the compiler.

For example, in POSIX shell: `scan-build sh -c '${CC} "$@"' cc main.c -o main`.

PowerShell may have similar syntax, but I'm not sure, DOS command line will need something radically different.

Comment: Credits're not mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38308269/6230282

Comment: 5 years later, the first helpful answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

be sure to use build-scan -v  (verbose) to see if actually running clang checker.
I followed this tutorial
http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~tianyi.zhang/tutorial.html
When I tried the C++ example it did not show any errors in the buggy code.
The -v showed me that the provided Makefile was broken - after I fixed that clang still did not detect the bugs but g++ shows the bug.

Maybe they turned that particular check off.
Clang Static Analyzer version 3.8
The tutorial uses version 3.2

Comment: I uninstalled Clang since I couldn't make it work, but I'll try to do this should I try again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not doing something right. 
For example, the third example Visual Studio 2015 even refused to compile with error:

> error C2124: divide or mod by zero.

I don't think Clang is not capable of detect something like that. However, this is not important.

I tried to check this code using PVS-Studio and it detected all three errors:

- V609 Divide by zero. Denominator 'h' == 0. MFCApplication2
  mainfrm.cpp 17
- V614 Uninitialized variable 'h' used. MFCApplication2
  mainfrm.cpp 23
- V609 Divide by zero. Denominator '0' == 0.
  MFCApplication2 mainfrm.cpp 28

Therefore, I recommend you still experiment. At least the third case should be exactly found by Clang.
A practical recommendation is to use more powerful tools, such as PVS-Studio, for analysis. He, by the way, [finds errors](https://www.viva64.com/en/inspections/#ID0ECKAG) in Clang and GCC.